# How to import variable from 'routes file' to 'components file' in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to import my variable `$HashOfRandomNumber` from my controller to my routes.

**Routes file**

```
Route::get('password/reset/{HashOfRandomNumber}', 'PasswordReset@reset');
```

**Component file**

```
class PasswordReset extends Controller
{
    public function reset()
    {
        #other my code...

        $HashOfRandomNumber = '912htfr0921fb21fuio';

        #other code...
    }
}
```

My method doesn't work.
 Could you tell me how to import my variable `$HashOfRandomNumber` from my controller to my routes, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to familiarize yourself with how URL parameters work. The route:

```
Route::get('password/reset/{HashOfRandomNumber}', 'PasswordReset@reset');
```

Is saying that, given the route `http://myapp/password/reset/912htfr0921fb21fuio`, the 3rd param is available as `$HashOfRandomNumber` in the Controller or function that handles it.

In your Controller, you'd add:

```
public function reset($HashOfRandomNumber){
  dd($HashOfRandomNumber); // 912htfr0921fb21fuio
}
```

This doesn't pass it to the routes, but rather passes it from the route to the Controller.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters for full details on how URL (Route) parameters work.

If this route needs to use `Request $request`, define it as the following:

```
public function reset(Request $request, $HashOfRandomNumber){
  dd($HashOfRandomNumber); // 912htfr0921fb21fuio
}
```

This route shouldn't need to inject `$request`, but that's the syntax.

Comment: I also have `Request $request` in my params of `reset` function and when im trying to add any other variable, `$HashOfRandomNumber` for example, i have an error: `Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\PasswordReset::reset(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: It can work with `Request $request`, you just need to add it first. I'll put an edit.

Comment: Wait, `PasswordReset::send()` is not the same as the method above. When is `send()` called?

Comment: I beg my pardon, i replaced `reset` with the `send` by the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The variable in the URL is passed to the controller as a paramater for the function, so you need to have a variable it can be assigned to.

```
public function reset()
```

Needs to be

```
public function reset($HashOfRandomNumber)
```